# ¿Como puedo Resolver error al usar el método substring en java?

Tags: java

mi inquietud es la siguiente:
Código [image: error_substring]

Adjunto en imagen el código para que puedan visualizar el error.. 
Quisiera saber porque me marca este error.. ? Si me pueden dar algún dato de sobre el uso de esta función agradecido y la mejor manera de importar ya que es reconocida en algunos ide de netbeans-8.1 y en otros no usando la misma versión versión 8.0.. No se si la versión influya en ello lo que me parece extraño..

el codigo que estoy intentando hacer es el siguiente:

```
substring(informacion.getString("DatosPersona"), 0,4));
substring(informationObrero.getString("DatosPersona"), 4,12));
```

Comment: ayudaría que nos pusieses lo que dice el error.

Comment: Como regal general: limita el uso de imágenes. Y utiliza el MVCE (minimal verifiable, complete example): la unidad de código más pequeña que reproduce el problema. E incluye siempre las excepciones completas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente substring es un método de la clase String, y dado que en tu pregunta hablas del método substring sospecho que eso es lo que intentas hacer.

Deberías quitar ese import y arreglar tu código, que seguramente esté incorrecto. No lo has puesto en esta pregunta así que no te puedo decir lo que has hecho mal.

Un ejemplo correcto sacado del manual de Java:

```
"hamburger".substring(4, 8); // Devuelve "urge"
"smiles".substring(1, 5) // Devuelve "mile"
String ejemplo = "ejemplo";
ejemplo.substring(1); // Devuelve "jemplo"
```

Sospecho que en tu código has utilizado substring como si fuera una clase o algo así.

Si realmente pretendías utilizar ese substring de Nashorn entonces puede ser que estés utilizando una versión de Java anterior a la 8.

Comment: Si creo que lo estaba haciendo de la manera incorrecta devido a que lo estaba colocando de la siguiente manera: substring(infomacion.getString("DatosPersonas"), 4,12);

Comment: Gracias Amigo, tu respuesta me ayudo mucho

Comment: @josé-romero entonces vota positivo mi respuesta y márcala como la respuesta válida ;) Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español

Answer (score 0):

El error marca una refrencia a la API Nashorn.
Esta API viene dentro de la version de Java 8 y se utiliza para correr codigo Javascript dentro de la Virtual Machine de Java. Deberías chequear, luego de importar el proyecto en el IDE, que el proyecto este configurado para compilar en Java 8.